# Site links working in Firefox but not in Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, safari, hyperlink

I'm having trouble getting my site links to work in Chrome and Safari. It works fine in Firefox but they don't show up as links in Chrome and Safari. I have a link for the header and for the "bio", "view reel" and e-mails. Can someone tell me how to fix this please? The code is below. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.studiogo.tv">

<body align="center">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="format.css">

<map id="home">
<area shape="rect" coords="134,10,902,151" href="http://www.studiogo.tv" />
</map>

<map id="links">
<area shape="rect" coords="325,165,426,188" href="http://www.bradgo.com/edit" alt="View Reel" title="View Reel"    />
<area shape="rect" coords="326,187,362,207" href="http://www.studiogo.tv/bgobio.html" alt="BGOBIO" title="BGOBIO"    />
<area shape="rect" coords="718,169,754,189" href="http://www.studiogo.tv/ngobio.html" alt="NGOBIO" title="NGOBIO"    />
<area shape="rect" coords="325,135,480,153" href="mailto:bradgo@gmail.com?subject="The Hush Project"" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="720,136,884,154" href="mailto:nicolekgo@gmail.com?subject="The Hush Project"" alt="" title=""    />
</map>

<table border="0" width="95%" align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan-"1" align="center" bgcolor="black"><img src="STUDIOGO_BANNER.png" usemap="#home" border="0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="1" align="center" bgcolor="black" border="0" width="95%">
<body align="center">

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ialX5OqPpv8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</br>
</body>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="1" align="center" bgcolor="black"><img src="STUDIOGO_BOTTOM.png" usemap="#links" border="0"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without an example but you can start with this:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="325,135,480,153" href="mailto:bradgo@gmail.com?subject='The Hush Project'" alt="" title=""    />
<area shape="rect" coords="720,136,884,154" href="mailto:nicolekgo@gmail.com?subject='The Hush Project'" alt="" title=""    />
```

You are using quotation marks for the mail subject and that messes up the link because the starting " of the subject actually closes the href. You should replace the quotation marks of the subject with '.